# Is bash doing "$@" expansion incorrectly inside ${var+...}?

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, posix, expansion

I currently get 2 opinions by 3 shells:

```
$ bash -c 'set bar; set foo${1+ "$@"}; echo "$# $*"'
1 foobar

$ ash -c 'set bar; set foo${1+ "$@"}; echo "$# $*"'
2 foo bar

$ dash -c 'set bar; set foo${1+ "$@"}; echo "$# $*"'
2 foo bar
```

Or did I overlook some POSIX definition which renders my example as implementation-defined behavior?

Note that only "$@" seems to trigger differences. The following works the same for all 3 shells:

```
$ bash -c 'set bar; set foo${1+ $*}; echo "$# $*"'
2 foo bar

$ ash -c 'set bar; set foo${1+ $*}; echo "$# $*"'
2 foo bar

$ dash -c 'set bar; set foo${1+ $*}; echo "$# $*"'
2 foo bar
```

Unfortunately, $* is not quite the same as "$@" if the arguments should contain whitespace.

BTW, I am using Bash version 4.4.12(1)-release.

Comment: Did you mean `'${1:+ "$@"}'` BTW?

Comment: @bipll, ...surely not with the literal single quotes -- those would end the string, and only the argument immediately following `sh -c` is parsed as code. Syntactic whitespace there would thus move some content intended to be parsed as script text into an argument that's literally never read.

Comment: @Guenther, you might explicitly contrast against the behavior of `echo foo${1+ bar}` to make the context a little more clear (in showing that the behavior differs between `"$@"` and other cases on bash, not just between `${var+ val}` on bash and other shells).

Comment: @bipll The missing ":" is intentional. I want no additional arguments to be generated for the case that no positional parameters should be set. For most shells, ${1+ "$@"} is exactly the same as "$@" alone. However, some older shells are said to expand "$@" to an empty argument rather than to no arguments at all if no positional arguments have been set. The ${1+...} construct works on all shells. Or at least I thought so... I got the trick from Tcl, where all scripts normally start with a prelude using the same trick.

Comment: @Charles Thanks for the tipp. I have updated the example accordingly.

Comment: I wonder whether the effect could be due to field splitting. POSIX says "After parameter expansion [...] the shell shall scan the results of expansions and substitutions that did not occur in double-quotes for field splitting [...]" In this case, even though the $@ itself is in double quotes, the enclosing ${1+...} isn't. As far as I can see, POSIX specifies no clear order between quote removal and field splitting for the case that a doubly-quoted parameter expansion takes place inside an unquoted parameter expansion.

Comment: On the other hand, the effect which one can observe here is rather field *merging* than field splitting.

Comment: If you don't get an answer here, I'd suggest taking this to the [bash-bugs mailing list](https://lists.gnu.org/mailman/listinfo/bug-bash). It's a good question!

Comment: @Charles Thanks for the advice! I will wait a bit whether something comes up in this thread, and turn to the bash-bugs list otherwise.

Comment: @GuentherBrunthaler News on this one?

Comment: @A.H. Nothing new. But I suppose it doesn't matter - even if that bug were fixed in new bash versions, it would still be present in all older installations. Therefore, using '${1:+ "$@"}' obviously cannot be portable because the bug is already out there. I changed my scripts into ' ${1:+"$@"}' (moving the space from after the "+" to before the first "$", which is less elegant and may create a trailing space, but at least it works - whether the bug is present or not. The extra space will be removed by the shell during the word splitting phase, so it is still correct although less efficient.

Comment: Hmm.  Not even `bash --posix -c 'set bar; set foo${1+ "$@"}; echo "$# $*"'` fixes this.

Comment: `zsh` is a bit different too:  `zsh -c 'set bar; set foo${1+ "$@"}; echo "$# $*"'` outputs `1 foo bar`.

Comment: try `bash -c 'set bar; set foo"${1+ "$@"}"; echo "$# $*"'`

Answer (score 1):

I tend not to trust spaces inside unquoted parameter expansion. I can't explain why it doesn't work, but I can give you a solution that does: move the space outside the parameter expansion. The `set` command doesn't mind trailing white space.

```
$ bash -c 'set bar; set foo ${1+"$@"}; echo "$# $*"'   # 5.0.2(1)
2 foo bar

$ dash -c 'set bar; set foo ${1+"$@"}; echo "$# $*"'   # 0.5.10.2
2 foo bar

$ ash  -c 'set bar; set foo ${1+"$@"}; echo "$# $*"'   # /bin/sh on FreeBSD 7.3
2 foo bar

$ ksh  -c 'set bar; set foo ${1+"$@"}; echo "$# $*"'   # 93u+ 2012-08-01
2 foo bar

$ zsh  -c 'set bar; set foo ${1+"$@"}; echo "$# $*"'   # 5.7
2 foo bar
```

(I ran everything on the latest Debian Testing except `ash`)

Comment: Yes, this is the same solution I am also using since I found out about the compatibility issues with my original approach. But I dislike the extra space which is added this way, and needs to be removed again later by the word-splitting phase. This creates useless additional work for the shell, which my original approach would have avoided. So it's a shame it did not work. But what can one do if bash doesn't like it, even if that should be the case due to a bug.

Comment: Can you quantify the work needed in that word-splitting phase? I'm not sure it even exists (isn't trailing white space automatically removed?) and if it does exist, I'd expect it to be trivial (by which I mean that if you see a performance hit, you should probably rewrite the whole thing in a more efficient language than bash).

Comment: The answer to that depends on the implementation. POSIX only defines what the shell should do, but not how to actually achieve it. But whether or not performance is affected by whitespace removal, I am sure the impact would be minimal. I am therefore not concerned about performance, but conceptional elegance. Putting a space where none is needed, only to be removed again later, is just nonsense. It makes no sense. However, it seems necessary here in order to work around that bash bug. I can live with that. But I don't like it.

Comment: I personally find the space outside the parameter expansion to be aesthetically preferable, but perhaps that's because I'm so very comfortable with programming languages that use spaces (rather than e.g. commas) to separate arguments. Obviously that's subjective. All that said, your method's failure to function here is most likely a bug in bash.

Answer (score 1):

Though this does *appear* to be a bug, I've run across some weird edge cases with "... $@" before, and this matches expected behavior, at least historically. `" $@"` (with hanging white space) is **undefined behavior**, because you're basically asking for all members of the `$@` array to be treated as args for the shell parser *plus one character of whitespace.* It can be a bit difficult to wrap your head around, and some of the things you've said are misleading, so I figured I'd provide more info and a tip for achieving better behavior.

The way you're using "$@" & trying to interchange it with "$*" is going to cause you issues. There are significant differences between `$*` and `$@` behavior that matches their intended usage. If you're using `$@`, it is because you want to do something like this:

```
wrapper_fxn() {
  wrapped_cmd "$@"
}
```

When you wrap $@ in quotes (and any other array for that matter), bash evaluates it *as if* each argument/member of the array is first wrapped in double quotes. However, there is a bit more magic involved, since it doesn't actually wrap it in double-quotes, but removes the double-quotes but indicates to change the parsing behavior at a later step.

The reason the special behavior of `"$@"` exists is to help deal with frustrating `quoting` & `argv` interference issues.

So, think of them like this:

- $@ : multiple args / for propagating args while preserving quoting of whitespace
- $* : single arg / for concatenating all strings in an array to be a single arg

My advice: don't do `"$@ "`; it is undefined behavior. As soon as you're quoting like `"$@"`, you're trying to do argument-expansion, and to add another argument or array of arguments, just do it like so:

```sh
# Making sure to have quotes around each new arg
somecmd "$newFirstArg" "$@" "${additionalArray[@]}" "$newLastArg"
```

... it will better communicate intention, and almost never yield unexpected behavior.

## More in depth

With all that said, the strange edge behavior of "$@" has to do when you use it like: `"... $@"`, as does " $@". Bash will merge one of the items of the array, depending on the position of `...` with the extra characters.

When you add anything to the right or left of `$@` in a quoted statement, *e.g.*   `"extra stuff $@"` or `"$@ extra stuff"`, what bash will do is just to add the `extra stuff` onto the first or last member of the array, respectively. The exception to this is if there is another array in the double-quoted statement, perhaps `$@` duplicated like so: `"$@ $@"`. It will actually merge the last item of the first array, with the first item of the last array. So, if `$@` has three members, the final `argv[]` of `"$@ $@"` will have 5 args, not 6.

Here is a utility function to help poke at the behavior:

```sh
# example function
print-args () 
{ 
    local i=0;
    for arg in "$@";
    do
        printf "[${i}]:%s\n" "\"$arg\"";
        let i++;
    done
}

# good example arg-set covering many of the important edge cases
set "one \"one" two three

# One case, modify it to see the various permutations of the edge cases
print-args " $@ $@ "
#>[0]:" one "one"
#>[1]:"two"
#>[2]:"three one "one"
#>[3]:"two"
#>[4]:"three "
```

Comment: Thanks four your explanations, but I am afraid you did not look at my code snippets thoroughly: I never used "$@ " but rather ${1+ "$@"}, so there was no space within the double quotes. The idea was to never generate that argument at all, unless arguments are actually present. What I do now, in order to avoid the bug/problem, is moving the space out of the whole construct and unconditionally before it. This works, although it is not as elegant as the initially intended variant (which avoided to generate the unnecessary trailing space in case of no arguments).